# Uniform Circular Motion

Tags: velocity

I am so confused on what approach to take when face with questions like find the angular velocity when I am given radius and time or radius and revolution/minutes. Are there any crucial key points to know? Or any key equations that I can use? Sorry, I tried learning on my own about the subject because my professor did a really bad job at explaining but I still have trouble. Any and all comments highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this as more of a broad conceptual understanding that is good to have to do well with these problems. The key is the fact that $\pi$ is the tie between the angular and the linear motion.

Let's say you're given radius and time for a revolution, you're trying to find the angular and linear velocity. Here's how I would approach it:

Let's say you run a lap around a circular track with a radius of 50 meters in 120 seconds. When you're done running that one lap, how far did you travel, both angularly and linearly?

Well, angularly speaking, if you ran around the full circular track in 120 seconds, that means that you traveled 360 degrees around the track (angularly speaking) in 120 seconds. So we divide. $360\ \deg / 120\ s$ = $3\deg/s$

But a lot of times we work in radians. 360 degrees is just $2\pi$ radians. So instead of 360 degrees, we write $2\pi$. So your angular speed would be (in rads/sec):

$$2\pi /120$$

Boom! That's already the formula $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$ that we just showed intuitively! $\omega$ is angular velocity, $T$ is your period (how long to go one revolution).

But what if I wanted to figure out how far I actually ran (distance-wise) on that track? Well in that 120 seconds, how far did I travel? Going back to geometry, I ran a whole circle circumference of radius $50m$. The formula for that is $2\pi r$.

So like before, we'll divide.

$$ v= \frac{2\pi * 50}{120} = 2.617 m / s$$

That gives us our other very important formula!

$$ v = \frac{2\pi r}{T}$$

Becuase $ v = \frac{2\pi r}{T}$ and $\omega = \frac{2\pi}{T}$, this means that $v = r\omega$. And there you have it, pretty much all the angular equations you need to know.

Comment: ohhhhh my gosh rb612 you being like god to me thanks so much best friend.Thanks.....-_-

Comment: @EmilyPerez you're welcome! If this fully answered your question please mark this as resolved by hitting the green checkmark next to this answer.

Comment: @EmilyPerez recall that centripetal force is mv^2/r, so you're going to have to calculate v first by using the formula I informally derived of $v = 2\pi r / T$